# How to enable dynamic theming at runtime in an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-12

I'm working on an Android app and I want to allow users to enable or disable dynamic theme feature on runtime. I'm not sure how to implement this feature. Can someone guide me through the process?

- My Android project is not based on Jetpack Compose.*

I would greatly appreciate any code examples, tutorials, or suggestions on how to achieve my goal in my Android app. Thank you in advance for your help!